# Where can I find a breakdown by race and gender of US CS bachelor's degrees?

Tags: equity

I know where to find [the percentage of CS bachelor's degrees going to women in the US (Figure 2-16)](https://nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsb20161/#/figures) and [the percentage of CS bachelor's degrees going to people of different ethnicities at research universities in the US and Canada participating in the Taulbee Survey (Table B-3)](http://cra.org/crn/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2017/05/2016-Taulbee-Survey.pdf). Where, if anywhere, can I find the percentage of bachelor's degree in CS, ideally over time, broken down by both ethnicity and gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible sources are

- [The Statistical Abstract of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_Abstract_of_the_United_States) (SAUS)
- The [Data USA](https://datausa.io/profile/cip/110701/) website.

Unfortunately SAUS went dark in 2012 but back additions can be found at the [Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/library/publications/time-series/statistical_abstracts.html). The latest numbers are old, but not yet irrelevant.

Sorry that this is just links, but I don't know what else to say.

Comment: The 2012 SAUS (Oct 2011) can be downloaded from https://www2.census.gov/library/publications/2011/compendia/statab/131ed/2012-statab.pdf

Comment: Thank you. The Data USA website held the most recent statistics in a convenient format. https://datausa.io/profile/cip/110701/#grads_ethnicity_gender

Answer (score 5):

the Taulbee report [An-In Depth Examination of Data and 
Trends Regarding Women in Computing](http://cra.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Data-Trends-Women-in-Computing-Sloan.pdf) provides summary data on computing degrees by ethnicity & gender for 2013 in Table 2 on pg 20 and cites the [Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System (IPEDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Postsecondary_Education_Data_System) as their data source. You can either filter through their data online or download it:

> Data are available starting with the 1980-81 collection year for the Complete data files and Custom data files functions, which zip the data into comma separated value (*csv). Beginning with the 2010-11 collection year, data for each collection year are compiled into an Access database.

Some tips for using their online data statistics:

- Try using the 'Statistical Tables' option on the 'Use the Data' page
- When select institutions, if you select 'By variables', there's an entry called 'Completions' which has an option for reporting 'Number of students receiving awards/degrees, by race/ethnicity and gender'
- After that, select the specific gender/ethnicity info you're filtering for

Comment: Thank you. FWIW, I tried going to IPEDS to get more recent data myself and couldn't figure out how to.

Comment: @EllenSpertus Yes, it's not very intuitive. I added some info on how I used their system.  Alternatively, you could contact their help desk by phone or email as described at https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/Home/Questions